# Spring Security SAML and OpenSAML 3

Tags: spring-security, spring-saml, opensaml

is it possible to you the new version of OpenSAML 3 instead of the old OpenSAML 2
in Spring Security SAML current stable version 1.0.10.RELEASE

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see that as a possibility because OpenSAML3 has major changes to package names and etc...

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?

Comment: I think we can try https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-saml2-service-provider. It uses opensaml v3 but there is still problem with migrating from opensaml 2 to opensaml 3. The only positive document is the commercial book https://payhip.com/b/41Tw